# How to align text vertically?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I have a line of code in my doc:

[image]

See how it's all the way at the top and left of the available space?

I'd like to have it centered vertically and horizontally within this space, something like this:

[image]

Is this possible without creating a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the text is in its own paragraph.
And it looks as if the paragraph attributes includes:

1. left-justified;
2. some indent, and
3. some "below" vertical space.

If this is the case, you could try changing the paragraph attributes by

1. Select the paragraph.
2. Remove the indent
3. Change the justification to centre
4. Add some "above" vertical space.

BTW, much of word's formatting is per-paragraph.
When working out this kind of issue it is helpful to display the paragraph markers so that you can see where the boundaries are.

To do this, find the set of options that control paragraph formatting
and locate a button with a paragraph symbol on it;
this symbol looks like a backwards P.
(On my version of word this is on the Home tab, next to some buttons that
control numbered paragraphs, bullet paragraphs, etc.)

When you press this button, you will see paragraph markers on the screen
(also space indicators, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
Although these markers won't appear on printed output.